# Did I break my system with autoremove?

Tags: apt

I have recently installed the wrong version of PlayOnLinux, and had to uninstall it. I did so via terminal with `sudo apt-get autoremove playonlinux`. But it seems I have uninstalled important stuff!! Sorry it's in portuguese.

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Os pacotes a seguir serão REMOVIDOS:
  icoutils imagemagick-6-common jq libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386
  libatspi2.0-0:i386 libcolord2:i386 libepoxy0:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libjq1
  libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libonig5 libpython2-stdlib
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib librest-0.7-0:i386
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 linux-headers-5.4.0-91
  linux-headers-5.4.0-91-generic linux-image-5.4.0-91-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-91-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-91-generic
  python-wxgtk3.0 python-wxversion python2 python2-minimal python2.7
  python2.7-minimal virtualbox virtualbox-qt wine-stable wine-stable-amd64
  wine-stable-i386:i386 wine-staging wine-staging-amd64 wine-staging-i386:i386
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 40 a serem removidos e 0 não atualizados.
Depois desta operação, 3.058 MB de espaço em disco serão liberados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n] s
(Lendo banco de dados ... 496141 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A remover icoutils (0.32.3-3) ...
A remover libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4) ...
A remover libmagickwand-6.q16-6:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4) ...
A remover libmagickcore-6.q16-6:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4) ...
A remover imagemagick-6-common (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4) ...
A remover jq (1.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
A remover libgtk-3-0:i386 (3.24.20-0ubuntu1) ...
A remover libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 (2.34.2-0ubuntu2~20.04.1) ...
A remover libatk1.0-0:i386 (2.35.1-1ubuntu2) ...
A remover libatspi2.0-0:i386 (2.36.0-2) ...
A remover libcolord2:i386 (1.4.4-2) ...
A remover libepoxy0:i386 (1.5.4-1) ...
A remover libjq1:amd64 (1.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
A remover libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 (1.4.4-2ubuntu2) ...
A remover liblqr-1-0:amd64 (0.4.2-2.1) ...
A remover libonig5:amd64 (6.9.4-1) ...
A remover python-wxgtk3.0 (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1) ...
A remover python-wxversion (3.0.2.0+dfsg-8build1) ...
A remover python2 (2.7.17-2ubuntu4) ...
A remover libpython2-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.17-2ubuntu4) ...
A remover python2.7 (2.7.18-1~20.04.1) ...
A remover libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.18-1~20.04.1) ...
A remover python2-minimal (2.7.17-2ubuntu4) ...
A remover python2.7-minimal (2.7.18-1~20.04.1) ...
Unlinking and removing bytecode for runtime python2.7
A remover libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.18-1~20.04.1) ...
A remover librest-0.7-0:i386 (0.8.1-1) ...
A remover libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 (2.70.0-1) ...
A remover linux-headers-5.4.0-91-generic (5.4.0-91.102) ...
A remover linux-headers-5.4.0-91 (5.4.0-91.102) ...
A remover linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-91-generic (5.4.0-91.102) ...
A remover linux-image-5.4.0-91-generic (5.4.0-91.102) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-91-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50_linuxmint.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Imagem Linux encontrada: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-94-generic
Imagem initrd encontrada: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-94-generic
Imagem Linux encontrada: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-92-generic
Imagem initrd encontrada: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-92-generic
Imagem Linux encontrada: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic
Imagem initrd encontrada: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
concluído
A remover linux-modules-5.4.0-91-generic (5.4.0-91.102) ...
A remover virtualbox-qt (6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
A remover virtualbox (6.1.26-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
A remover wine-stable (6.0.2~focal-1) ...
A remover wine-stable-amd64 (6.0.2~focal-1) ...
A remover wine-stable-i386:i386 (6.0.2~focal-1) ...
A remover wine-staging (7.0~rc5~focal-1) ...
A remover wine-staging-amd64 (7.0~rc5~focal-1) ...
A remover wine-staging-i386:i386 (7.0~rc5~focal-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
A processar 'triggers' para libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
A processar 'triggers' para man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para desktop-file-utils (0.24+linuxmint1) ...
```

A lot of kernel, grub and boot related stuff is mentioned. The system still functions properly, but last time I had an issue with boot and grub I only found out when I rebooted and the OS wouldn't load.

Did I F up?

Comment: A few of those packages might be important for your workflow, but I don't see anything critical in that output. Your system should still boot.

Comment: @user535733 Not even "linux-modules-5.4.0-91-generic"?

Comment: Your current kernel is `Imagem Linux encontrada: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-94-generic` so the one that is being removed is expected since it is an older kernel.

Comment: And please note `autoremove`is to be used by itself, not to uninstall a package. What you want is probably `sudo apt remove --purge playonlinux`.

Comment: In the future, if you prefix your command with `LC_ALL=C`, as in `LC_ALL=C sudo apt autoremove playonlinux`, then the output will be in english.

Comment: You can use `autoremove` when removing a package, but it is done as `sudo apt remove --autoremove playonlinux` then it removes all of the dependencies as well at the same time.

Comment: @ChanganAuto You can also use the shorter `apt purge X`.

Comment: @marcelm Indeed :) But for newbies I always post the "extended version" in order to provide a better understanding of the underlying logic.

Answer (score 12):

The **autoremove** is used to get rid of old and/or no longer needed dependencies.  The *linux-modules-* and *linux-headers-* that you see removed are likely from a previous kernel that has since been updated.  If you do a `uname -r` you should see a release number that is greater than the one you removed.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get autoremove` does not take any arguments.  So these two lines are equivalent (the `<package>` argument is ignored):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoremove <package>
```

A few points on installing packages:

- `sudo apt-get install <package>` installs `<package>` and all dependencies.  `<package>` is marked as "manually installed".
- `sudo apt-get purge <package>` purges `<package>` but leaves its dependencies
- `sudo apt-get autoremove` purges any packages that are not dependencies for anything "manually installed".
- `apt-mark showmanual` will show you your list of manually installed packages.
- `apt-mark manual <package>` will set a package as "manually installed" so it will not be autoremoved.

I added info about `apt-mark` just so you know what's going on. It's mostly unnecessary to ever use that. `autoremove` is quite safe because it never uninstalls something that you've explicitly installed.